# Изменение праметра реестра

Tags: c++, winapi, реестр

Нужно изменить параметр реестра.В интернете нашёл пару примеров, воспроизвёл - и ничего не получилось, `GetLastError()` возвращает 0. Поэтому обращаюсь за помощью)  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting`, параметр `DontShowUI` (тип `REG_DWORD`) нужно выставить в 1.

Делаю так и ничего не меняется

```
HKEY hkey;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Windows Error Reporting\\", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hkey);

RegSetValue(hkey, TEXT("DontShowUI"), REG_DWORD, L"1", sizeof(L"1"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Не заметил, в win-32 нужно использовать `RegSetValueEx`